# Don't understand why I am getting this error: Member reference base type 'Shape *' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++

I have been reading this book on game engines and I am following along with code examples. I believe I have set up the omitted code properly (I just had to include list and main()) so that it can compile.

I have been getting an error that says Member reference base type 'Shape *' is not a structure or union and I have looked up what this error means but each question I find has a different type of answer. I copied it word for word from  the book and I am a little confused as to why I am getting this. Here is an image of the [image: code].

Any insight would be helpful!

EDIT: The only difference between the code in the book and mine (aside from the omited code to make it runable) is adding override after each pure virtual function

Comment: Post your code, not screenshots of code

Comment: Please post the code itself. It helps.
Try `(*pShape)->Draw()`

Also show where you are initializing your object

Comment: @Waqar sorry about that, first time ever posting! Thank you I forgot I have to put a de-referenced pointer in parentheses

Comment: Great. @vll posted a great answer. If it fixes your problem, accep the answer :)

On a side note, I like your color scheme, mind sharing the name of this color scheme?

Comment: @Waqar it's the default dark theme on my Macbook's XCode

Answer (score 1):

Operator `->` is executed on the iterator, which returns `Shape*` and then attempts to access `Draw()` member function of the pointer. Pointers have no member functions, so this fails. You have to dereference the iterator first, then call `->` operator on the returned pointer:

```
(*pShape)->Draw();
// Same thing as:
// Shape* ptr = *pShape;
// ptr->Draw();
```

Comment: Thank you! I originally had *pShape -> Draw() and forgot that -> had precedence over * and didn't put it in parentheses.